# Uploading PDFs with Imagick extension enabled seems to rasterize and compress the PDFs

Tags: assets, upload, pdf, imagick

Uploading PDFs to Craft3 with Imagick extension enabled seems to rasterize and compress the PDFs.

Also, if I manually swap out the files after upload, it works fine until I have to edit something in an article with a pdf uploaded. Then the behavior is repeated when I press save.

Any idea on where to disable this behavior?

Comment: Can you verify if you see the same behavior in Craft 2?

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem with Craft3 (3.0.0-beta.19). Had to change the imageDriver to GD.

Add `'imageDriver' => 'gd',` to `config/general.php` and replace/reupload the files in Craft.